# First Example in JQgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php, mvcjqgrid

I am new to jqgrid. I want to use it in my project. I have set up php server. I want simple operations like sorting, grouping, editing, saving etc. I am comfortable with showing data, sort it and group it using jqgrid but I am not sure how to show, store and edit the data on local server. Can someone help me with it? If there is any working demo then please share it with me.

Comment: I just feel I have to make you aware of this.. punctuation is used at the end of a sentence, not the start.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have made the respective changes.Waiting for the answer.

Comment: Have you asked Google? There is at least one example for each of your questions.